# Unable to query postgress sql from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, jboss

I am trying to extract the data from Postgress DB, I am using the below code to get the data and it's working for those query which returns results within a second but not working when execution time > 4 sec

```
connection = psycopg2.connect('connection string')
cursor = connection.cursor()
postgreSQL_select_Query = """ SLECT * FROM TABLEA """
cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
```

It is throwing the below error for big query

> ('Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL', OperationalError('TEIID30504 nz_security_src: TEIID11009 java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@14b492f7[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@49b199 connection handles=0 lastUse=1581690750049 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@7ad42622 pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@62c5cfd8[pool=source] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@7528aaf6[connectionListener=14b492f7 connectionManager=6b1b6361 warned=false currentXid=null productName=Netezza NPS productVersion=Release 7.2.0.5-P2 [Build 45588] jndiName=java:/source] txSync=null]\nDETAIL:  org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: TEIID30504 nz_security_src: TEIID11009 java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@14b492f7[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@49b199 connection handles=0 lastUse=1581690750049 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@7ad42622 pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@62c5cfd8[pool=source] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@7528aaf6[connectionListener=14b492f7 connectionManager=6b1b6361 warned=false currentXid=null productName=Netezza NPS productVersion=Release 7.2.0.5-P2 [Build 45588] jndiName=java:/source] txSync=null]\n',))

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how your python code returned a stack trace from java.

Comment: It could be coming from the driver